# How to create a global variable with Play Framework 2.0

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

How do I create a global object/variable in Play Framework 2.0 using Scala?

I want to create a object that once instantiated, can persist between multiple controller actions so that different actions can still call on the same object (because initializing the object is very expensive).

Is this possible without storing it into the DB? I tried sticking the object into a the Global object for the onStart method as shown here:

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaGlobal

This was my code:

(in the root application folder)

```
object Global extends GlobalSettings {

  override def onStart(app:Application) {
    var foo = new Foo
    }
  }

}
```

And in my controller actions I try just calling the variable by name, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please show some code you've tried. I've successfully used Global (needs to be in default package).

Comment: Actually, I may have an answer in my [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091902/best-way-to-define-globals-in-a-play-2-0-application), but are wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: Thanks, your code in the related question works for me! I also changed my question to show what code I had.

Comment: OK, I'll add the code below as an answer for you to accept, if you wish :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your globals also need to be available to the methods in `Global`, put them in Global.scala like so:

```
package object globals {
  lazy val abc = Play.maybeApplication.flatMap(_.configuration.getString("abc")).getOrElse("default_value_of_abc")
  lazy val someActor = Akka.system.actorOf(Props[SomeActor], name = "someActor")
}
```

And then use it in your controllers like this:

```
println(globals.abc)
globals.someActor ! SomeMessage
```

**UPDATE**

The documentation has since been updated how add `Global.scala` in an idiomatic Play! way, with docs for both [Scala](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaGlobal) and [Java](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaGlobal).

Comment: Do you know how to do it in Java ?